# find possibilities of each type in a sliding window

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe and in the dataframe there is a column named "Type". like this:

|  | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 7 | 4 |
| 8 | 2 |

what i want is to find possibility of occurrence of each type in like each previous 5 rows. so for the table above  we have something like this: (POx-5 is possibility of occurrence of Type x in previous 5 rows.)

|  | Type | PO1-5 | PO2-5 | PO3-5 | PO4-5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0.2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0 | 0.2 |
| 3 | 3 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| 4 | 2 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| 5 | 2 | 0 | 0.6 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| 6 | 3 | 0 | 0.4 | 0.4 | 0.2 |
| 7 | 4 | 0 | 0.4 | 0.4 | 0.2 |
| 8 | 2 | 0 | 0.6 | 0.2 | 0.2 |

how can I do this and add it to the dataframe? I have no clue at all how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the answer but just wanted to leave the question here for if anyone hit the same problem:

say we have 4 types:

```
for i in range(4):
    df['PO'+str(i+1)+'-4'] = df['Type'].rolling(5).apply(lambda v: sum(v == i+1)/4)
```